# mysql_fetch_array returns wrong rows count

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
public function getRecurringEventsByGrouped($grouped){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `event` AS e
    WHERE e.`grouped` = " . $grouped . " ORDER BY EventId DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($ids[] = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) ;
    return $ids;
}
```

`mysql_fetch_array()` doesn't return the first row. `mysql_num_rows()` returns correct row count.

I also tried this query in HeidiSQL and it gave the same rows number as `mysql_num_rows()`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: Refactor your `[]=` loop, right now you're putting a useless false value into `$ids` after `fetch_array` is done.

Comment: 1) Oy, mysql_* functions. 2) I see no row counting. 3) Your while loop is malformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to iterate through the data in while loop.

```
$ids = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
   //check for proper indexing of table rows and specify $row[value] accordingly.
   $ids[] = $row[0];
}
return $ids;
```

this should fetch you the correct content.